# Is ASCON cipher broken?

Tags: cryptanalysis, encryption

http://eprint.iacr.org/2015/030 present several attacks of ASCON but does not have a conclusion section.

I'm having troubles estimating what are the consequences on the use of ASCON. What's your opinion about it ?

Comment: It only talks about round reduced versions, so it's not a break.

Comment: Its by the designers of ASCON. If it would be devastating, then they would already have withdrawn their submission.

Comment: I understand it is not devastating. Any suggestion about how to evaluate the seriousness of it ?